# Change gridview dataitem property in row databound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to do a string replace on one of a gridview's dataitem properties in the rowdatabound event (i.e. I would like for it to show up in the gridview slightly different than what it actually is).

in the rowdatabound event I have the following:

```
???? = (DataBinder.Eval(rowData, "SummaryId") as string).Replace("&", "").Replace("@", "");
```

What should the left half of the expression be?

Answer (score 0):

I never do it that way but, if you have to, I would say:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[n].Text = e.Row.Cells[n].Text.Replace("&", "").Replace("@", "");
}
```

where n is the column index.